# What should I do if my headphones don't go into my iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, hardware, headphones

When I put my headphones into my iPhone It doesnt go completely in like it should. I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just check and make sure there isn't any lint in there. otherwise, if it's the body of the connector touching the body of the iPod and not allowing it to fully connect then you need an M-F 1/8th inch extension adapter. Should be able to find one on digikey.com for cheap.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the headphones you try (you should try different sets) can physically fit into the port, then there is probably something lodged down in the port. Shine a light down it and see if you can find anything. If you have repeatedly tried to dislodge whatever may be there but seem unable to get it out, go to an Apple store and see what they have to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

Does audio still output to the headphones?

If not, take it to an Apple Store to see if it can be replaced. Or, call up your service provider and see if they can fix it for a cheaper cost than buying another phone.

Answer (score 0):

Look down inside the 3.5 mm plug housing (on phone) il bet ya have pulled th tip off th head phone jack an it's still lodged inside :(